# Django. Chain select_related()

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

this is a simple question:

Does it make sense, or is it possible to chain `select_related` on a query like this?:

```
queryset = a.objects.filter(...).select_related("b").select_related("c")
```

A has a ForeignKey to B, B has a ForeignKey to C. My models look like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
 b = models.ForeignKey(B)

class B(models.Model):
 c = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
queryset = a.objects.filter(...).select_related("b__c")
```

[See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    # ...
    hometown = models.ForeignKey(City)

class Book(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

and the query:

```
b = Book.objects.select_related('author__hometown').get(id=4)
p = b.author         # Doesn't hit the database.
c = p.hometown       # Doesn't hit the database.
```

Comment: You don't actually need to do any chaining here. `select_related('b__c')` necessarily implies `select_related('b')` already.